# Redirect to google Login page after Login in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.8

I am try to run an existing laravel project but after login it will redirect to login page instead of home page. I check in the middleware auth::user is empty also. Need help in it.

Comment: After Auth::login($user, true); i try dd(Auth::user()); it work but after redirection dd(Auth::user()); prints null

Comment: Do you have any log records regarding authentication? It seems to me there is something wrong with sessions.